# CSVHelper Error involving CurrentIndex and Inner Exception "Path is not of a valid form."

Tags: csvhelper

Framework 4.7.2

C#

CSVHelper 27.0.4

Problem:
When using `GetRecords<T>` CSVReader is throwing a ReaderException at CurrentIndex 92.

I have no idea what CurrentIndex is the index of.  To made my troubleshooting as simple as possible, I have a one-line CSV file with/without CRLF. Same error either way. There are only 46 columns.

This is my CSVConfig:

```
           csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
           csvConfiguration.Delimiter = ",";
           csvConfiguration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
           
           csvConfiguration.Quote = '\'';
           csvConfiguration.BadDataFound = null;
           csvConfiguration.MissingFieldFound = null;
```

Here's where I attempt to read the CSV file

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(base.FileToImport.FileToImport.FullName))
 {
  using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfiguration))
  {
   recordlist.AddRange(csvReader.GetRecords<T>());
  }
 }
```

Here's my locals of the csvReader:
[Local Debug Window, showing most things are in order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R79f.png)

There's an inner exception of
"The Path is not of a legal form"

at System.IO.Path.NewNormalizePath(String path, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)

at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)

at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)

at System.IO.FileInfo.Init(String fileName, Boolean checkHost)

at System.IO.FileInfo..ctor(String fileName)

at CsvHelper.Expressions.RecordCreator.CreateT

at CsvHelper.Expressions.RecordManager.CreateT

at CsvHelper.CsvReader.d__87`1.MoveNext()

The file path of the StreamReader is: \\[a server that isn't my dev pc]\[share]\[folder]\onerow2021-03-23_001029715.ParcelManifest-Memphis.wms

## Edit: I figured it out...

The Class that I'm passing into `GetRecords<T>` had an a final property that I had neither an Index attribute nor an Ignore attribute for.  Adding the Ignore attribute resolved the Exception.

Answer (score 1):

The Class that I'm passing into GetRecords had an a final property that I had neither an Index attribute nor an Ignore attribute for. Adding the Ignore attribute resolved the Exception.